# как тестировать react native app

Tags: reactjs, android-sdk, virtualbox, react-native

Как тестировать react native app на телефоне если нет виртуализации на компе и нет возможности закачать expo на телефон, возможно есть что то толковое онлайн ? 
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте без установки на телефон - онлайн через [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/).

Но я бы рекомендовал отладку на телефоне через ADB, правда только для Android(для iOS без лицензии девелопера невозможно дебажить на устройстве). Это быстрее и продуктивнее.
Подробнее в [официальной документации](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)(англ).